# REPL.it JSON Files

Tags: python, discord.py, read-eval-print-loop

So recently I've been using REPL as python code source, but whenever I'm offline, any information stored in the JSON File is rolled back after a bit of time.  Now I know this is a REPL specific problem after doing some research, but is there any way I can fix this?  My code itself is quite a few lines long, so I would rather not want to use a completely different storage method.

Answer (score 0):

To successfully store data in json files in [replit.com](https://replit.com), it's important to load and dump it the correct way.

An example of storing data in json files:

```
with open("sample.json", "r") as file:
   sample = json.load(file)

sample["item"] = "Value"

with open("sample.json", "w") as file:
   json.dump(sample, file)
```

Let me know if you've already followed these steps.

Comment: Yeah, I have, but it's not exactly the problem about storing it itself.  Apparently, REPL once went through a DDoS attack because of offline JSON storing, so they just took this extra precaution.  It apparently just rolls back automatically.

Comment: I was unaware of this as JSON files have always worked in replit.com for me. Sorry but I cannot provide a better answer.